# All complex numbers with modulus 1 that are roots of a positive integer polynomial

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

How to find all θ, such that $e^{iθ}$ is a root of some positive integer coefficient polynomial P(x).

It's obvious that $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$ must be algebraic. Moreover, if for some positive integer m, $\cos(m\theta)$ is rational, such $e^{i\theta}$ is a root of some positive integer coefficient polynomial P(x). So far, my conjecture is: iff for some positive integer m, $\cos(m\theta)$ is rational, $e^{iθ}$ is a root of some positive integer coefficient polynomial P(x).

I've been stuck with the problem for days :(. You don't have to provide full solutions, some inspirational ideas are also welcome. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: “,… such $\theta$ exists.” Well, I think you mean that $\theta$ matches the condition, not that some other $\theta$ might exist. There is a lot of weird language in this post, like “$P(x)$ is a positive integer coefficient,” rather than “$P(x)$ has positive integer coefficients.”

Comment: Can you give an outline of your proof if $\cos(m\theta)$ is rational? I see it when $\cos (m\theta)$ is a negative rational number…

Comment: If $cos(m\theta)$ is rational, we can first easily prove that there exists some positive integer n, such that $cos(mn\theta)$ is a negative rational. Then, let it $cos(mn\theta)=$ -p/q (p,q are coprime positive integer). Then, $e^{imn\theta}$ must be a root of positive integer coefficient quardratic polynomial, $qx^2+2px+q$. After that, we can get another positive integer coefficient polynomial, $qx^{2n}+2px^n+q$, such that $e^{i\theta}$ is a root of it.

Comment: Okay, that works for all $\cos(m\theta)$ rationals *other than* $1.$

Comment: More generally, if $\theta$ is a solution, then any $\theta/m$ is a solution, since if $p(z)$ works for $e^{i\theta},$ then $p(z^m)$ works for $e^{i\theta/m}.$

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You talk of polynomials with positive integer coefficients and the write down polynomials which have zero as a coefficient so it's unclear what you want.

Regardless, your characterization is not correct. The irreducible polynomial

$$x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0$$

has a pair of complex conjugate roots $\alpha$ with absolute value one, but is also has another pair of roots $\beta$ and $\beta^{-1}$ with
$$\beta = -1.883203505913525864\ldots $$
Now we find that $\alpha = e^{i \theta}$ satisfies

$$2 \cos \theta = \alpha + \alpha^{-1} = \sqrt{2} - 1,$$
whereas
$$\beta + \beta^{-1} = -\sqrt{2} - 1.$$

You can see that $2 \cos n \theta \in \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ will never be rational for $n \ge 1$ in a number of ways.

For example, since $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer, so is $\alpha^n$ and thus so is $2 \cos(n \theta) \in [-2,2]$. But if the latter is rational then it is a rational algebraic integer which must be an integer. But now if $2 \cos(n \theta) \in \{-2,1,0,1,2\}$, then $2 \cos(12 n \theta) = 2$, but then $\alpha^{12 n} = 1$, and $\alpha$ is a root of unity. But $\alpha$ is not a root of unity because it has conjugates which do not have absolute value one.

Or, by Galois theory: there is an automorphism $\sigma$ satisfying $\sigma \alpha = \beta$. But if $\cos n \theta$ was rational, then

$$2 \cos(n \theta) = \alpha^n + \alpha^{-n} = 2 \cos n \theta = \sigma (2 \cos n \theta)
= \sigma \alpha^n + \sigma \alpha^{-n} = \beta^n + \beta^{-n}.$$

This equality can't hold, because the first expression is a real number in $[-2,2]$, whereas the last is a real number in $(-\infty,2) \cup (2,\infty)$ since $\beta^n$ is real and $|\beta| > 1$.

More generally, if $\beta \in [-1,0]$ is any real algebraic number which is a root of a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $d$ with positive integer coefficients, then

$$\alpha = \beta + \sqrt{\beta^2 - 1} = \beta + i \sqrt{1 - \beta^2}$$

is an algebraic number of absolute value one which is a root of

$$x^d P((x + x^{-1})/2)$$

which will also have positive integer coefficients. But $\alpha$ will generally not be a root of unity (for example, that implies that $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbf{Q}(\beta)$ are abelian Galois extensions) which will rarely be the case. Moreover, you can generate lots of $\beta$ by taking random polynomials with integer coefficients with at least one real root, and then scaling the polynomials so that they have a real root in $[-1,0]$.
Another general example; take

$$P(x) = x^3 + a x^2 + b x + 1.$$

where $a$ and $b$ are positive and $b > a$. Since $P(0) = 1$ and $P(-1) = a - b < 0$, there is a root $\beta \in (-1,0)$. Since there are no integer roots $P(x)$ is irreducible. $P(x)$ can have no positive real roots because the coefficients are positive. Now take

$$\alpha = \beta + \sqrt{\beta^2 - 1}$$

which is a root of

$$x^6 + 2 a x^5 + (3 + 4 b) x^4 + (8 + 4 a) x^3 + (3 + 4 b) x^2 + 2 a x + 1 = 0.$$

Since $\mathbf{Q}(\beta) \subset \mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\alpha$ is not real, the latter has degree $6$. If $\alpha$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity, it follows that $n \ge 7$. But then some conjugate of $\beta$ will be $2 \cos(2 \pi/n) > 0$, but this contradicts the fact that the roots of $P(x)$ are not positive. Hence these $\alpha = e^{i \theta}$ will never be roots of unity and (as in the first example above) $\cos(n \theta)$ will never be rational.

Comment: Great examples - If an algebraic number $z$ has some positive power $z^n$ that lives in an imaginary quadratic extension, then all it's algebraic conjugates have the same modulus   (and are $\alpha z, \alpha \bar z, \alpha^n=1$

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciated!!!